# Quel terme rendrait compte d’un homme qui prétend avoir une conduite exemplaire?

Tags: choix-de-mot, terminologie, formulation-idiomatique

Suite:

Et que les personnes avec qui il parle savent que ce qu’il affirme est à l’opposé de ce qu’elles savent. Il cherche à comprendre pourquoi certains hommes sont infidèles à leur femme tout en plaçant à distance sa propre conduite.

Comment: Accessoirement, si je comprends bien le propos, je dirais "Que les personnes avec qui il parle SACHENT que ce qu'il affirme..."

Comment: L’ajout de « et » devrait résoudre le problème de conjugaison.

Comment: Effectivement :-)

Comment: @Personne. Je suis de ton avis pour ce qui est de « ce qu’ELLES savent, étant donné que ce pronom renvoie à « les personnes » », en revanche il est bien question de « il, l’homme concerné» qui cherche à comprendre les écarts de conduite des hommes infidèles, y compris de ceux avec qui il converse, et qui s’exempte malhonnêtement de ce sous-groupe.

Comment: En réalité les autres hommes sont au courant qu’il est hypocrite dans toute sa conduite, ils savent qu’il se fait passer pour ce qu’il n’est pas, qu’il n’est pas un homme de bonnes vertus, tant s’en faut!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cet homme est hypocrite. Il fait preuve d'[hypocrisie](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/hypocrisie/41171), laquelle étant une

> Attitude consistant à dissimuler son caractère ou ses intentions
> véritables, à affecter des sentiments, des opinions, des vertus qu'on
> n'a pas, pour se présenter sous un jour favorable et inspirer
> confiance.

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire un [tartufe ou tartuffe](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tartufe#fr).

Comment: Comme il y a une notion de recherche méthodologique dans la question, on trouve de nos jours l'espèce *Tartuffe* avec des degrés plus élevés de perversion de la parole chez les *mythomanes*, les *manipulateurs*, les *psychopathes* et autres troubles égotique à tous les échelons de tous les composants de la société. — Utiliser ces mots pour des descriptions *ad hominem* n'est pas prudent et ne résout pas le problème, parler de "Tartufferie"  pour parler des actes de telles personnes est beaucoup plus aisé.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the contexte:

> faux jeton, faux derche, faux cul (vulgar!)

can be used instead of hypocrite.

Answer (score 0):

On pourrait dire d'un tel homme "qu'il joue les prudes".

Une personne prude est une personne à la morale stricte et excessive, parfois un peu naïve.

Jouer les prudes signifie agir comme s'il on était prude, mais en réalité on ne l'est pas.